# Dynamically adding a dropdownlist to a template column within an ASP.NET gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that I am dynamically creating and populating.

```
GridView myGrid = new GridView();
myGrid.Showfooter = true;

myGrid.Columns.Add(new BoundField() { HeaderText = "Serial #", DataField = "serial_number" });
...
...
...
myGrid.DataSource = myDS;
myGrid.DataBind();
```

My problem is that I'm having problems figuring out how to add a templatecolumn with a dropdownlist  in it.   Any ideas?

Thanks and Happy Holidays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a dropdownlist programmatically via a templatefield you first need to create a class that implements ITemplate and pass that to the ItemTemplate property of the templatefield.

a clear example is stated  [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.templatefield.aspx)

although the example doesn't use a dropdownlist, the concept is essentially the same.